# Why jdbc mysql connector can connect SSL required server without any ssl option?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I configured MySQL server on Amazon RDS with SSL required,
like this

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

and I confirmed that I can connect the server using mysql cli only when ssl options are given.

```
# ok
mysql -D xxx -uxxx -hxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -P3306 --ssl-ca=path/to/rds-ca-2019-root.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert -p

# connection error
mysql -D xxx -umyusername-hxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -P3306 -p
```

However, I can connect the server using JDBC mysql connector without any ssl option.

```
    var con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/xxx",
        "myusername",
        "<password>");
    var rs = con
        .prepareStatement("show status like 'Ssl_cipher'")
        .executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1));  // Ssl_cipher
      System.out.println(rs.getString(2));  // AES256-SHA
    }
```

Why this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that mysql connector skips verification of server certificate on default.
Explicitly passing verifyServerCertificate=true results in connection failure.